# How to get winapi thread HANDLE from QThread?

Tags: qt, winapi, handle

I would like to use `CancelSynchronousIo()` function, so I need a thread handle. In my QT app I have two threads: mainThread ( gui ) and secondThread for calculations. I would like to use `CancelSynchronousIo()` in mainThread to cancel operations in the secondThread. I don't know how to get winapi thread handle from Qt class.

I tried:

MainThread:

```
   thread = new QThread(this);
   simpleObject = new SimpleClass();
   connect(this, &MainWindow::getHandle, simpleObject , &simpleClass::getHandle);
   simpleObject->moveToThread(thread);
   thread->start();
```

SimpleObject, which is in the second thread:

```
void simpleClass::getHandle()   // this is slot in simpleObject, which is in the second thread
{
   emit handleFromSecondThread(GetCurrentThread());
}
```

I see that value from GetCurrentThread() in second thread is the same as value from GetCurrentThread() in mainThread

Comment: *I see that value from GetCurrentThread() in second thread is the same as value from GetCurrentThread() in mainThread* of course, because this api always return `( (HANDLE)(LONG_PTR) -2 ) `

Comment: @RbMm Yes, you are right. I always get ```0xfffffffffffffffe```. But how to do this?

Comment: I think something like [`OpenThread(READ_CONTROL | THREAD_QUERY_INFORMATION, FALSE, QThread::currentThreadId())`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-openthread) on the IO thread should give you the HANDLE.  The only issue is how best to communicate that HANDLE value to the other thread that wants to make the `CancelSynchronousIo` call.  Difficult to say more without seeing more code.

Answer (score 0):

You need [QThread::currentThreadId()](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qthread.html#currentThreadId), which returns the **ID** of the thread it is executed in, i.e. it calls [GetCurrentThreadId()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-getcurrentthreadid). You can then get the **handle** by calling [OpenThread()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-openthread) with that ID.

Note that this is different from [GetCurrentThread()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-getcurrentthread) which returns a constant that simply means "the current thread".

Comment: `QThread::currentThreadId()` return not thread handle but thread id. then question for which thread it returned id ? for some instance of `QThread` ? but in this case function can not be static. if it static - it can only return id for the the currently executing thread. which is pointless at all

Comment: @RbMm thanks, I edited my answer to convert from the ID to the actual HANDLE. And yes, it is a static function, so calling it on an instance of QThread will not yield the ID of that thread but always the ID of the calling thread.

Comment: but this id of calling thread, when we need how minimum id for another thread

Comment: In order for `QThread::currentThreadId()` to return the correct ID, you would need to call it inside the context of the thread itself, ie inside of `QThread::run()`. Which means not using `QThread` directly, but rather deriving from `QThread` so you can override `run()`.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, `QThread` does not provide access to either the `HANDLE` or the `ID` of the underlying OS thread.  The only way I can think of for you to get the thread's `HANDLE` is to derive a new class from `QThread` and override its virtual `run()` method to do one of the following:

- call `QThread::currentThreadId()` (or `GetCurrentThreadId()` directly), and then pass the returned `ID` to `OpenThread()`.
- call `GetCurrentThread()`, and then pass the returned pseudo-handle to `DuplicateHandle()`.